# Comma preceding "with" clause at end of sentence

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, dependent-clause

I read a sentence that I found very awkward:

> "This March was the hottest of the decade with every day above average."

My brain wants to add a comma before "with." I know one way to avoid the sentence altogether is to rephrase it as:

> "With every day above average, this March was the hottest of the decade."

But, if I were not to rephrase it as such, would it be correct to add a comma or to leave it in its original form?

Edit: My original sentence is not very clear; I made it up quickly just as an example. A better example might be:

> "It was the best game of the season with every player scoring at least one goal."

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have another go, if you don't mind.
 I think it needs the comma, otherwise it reads that this game was the best game of all the games played this season in which every player scored. With a comma it gives the impression that this game was the one and only game of the season in which every player scored, which, I think, is what you wanted it to say.

Comment: Thank you! I think you got it -- this is why the original structure just seemed off to me. It was saying the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Without the comma the sentence describes March as being part of a decade during which every single day was above average.
Whether every day of said decade was above average heat, or  above average something else, is a question.
Even with the comma it needs the word temperature at the end.
(I just joined about an hour ago so please forgive this answer if it offends in it's immaturity. )

Comment: Hi Carol, thank you. I actually just made up the sentence really quickly because the real sentence is work-related, so I can't share it. My main question is about the "with" clause -- I will update my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am studying comma rules currently.  Above all rules, there is the voice to use a comma where it is necessary to make your sentence easy to understand for your readers. Also rewriting it.

Including the subordinating conjunctions and about 16 other confirmed comma-rules, I wether find a rule for a sentence starting with "With" nor for
"with in the middle" where to put a comma. So listen to the voice above :-)

When we seeing the first phrase as intro, yes, the comma-rules say put a comma before the second phrase.

"With every day above average, this March was the hottest of the decade."

Comment: It's a parenthetical phrase adding detail to the main clause. Initially placed parentheticals are normally set off by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I found following on Cambridge Dictionary

SENSES !

B2 [ C ] an ability to understand, recognize, value, or react to something, especially any of the five physical abilities to see, hear, smell, taste, and feel:

With her excellent sense of smell, she could tell if you were a smoker from the other side of the room.

Answer (score 0):

I hate superfluous commas and other punctuation marks, but in your sentence the comma is obviously missing.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. You are perfectly right. I should have explained why. No sweat, I'll watch it in future.